# Unexpected output on pushing and retrieving values from c++ vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, iterator

I wrote the following program for pushing and printing values into a vector. It seems that if I push as well as print values from  a vector, it gives me undefined behaviour. For example, my expected output should have been: (1, 3, 4, 5) while I am getting the output as (0, 3, 4, 5). Can someone please explain as to where am I going wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<unsigned> vec;
    vec.push_back(1); vec.push_back(3); vec.push_back(4); vec.push_back(5);

    for(vector<unsigned>::iterator i=vec.begin(), l=vec.end(); i!=l; ++i){
        vec.push_back(2);
        cout<<(*i)<<"\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I heard that iterators for `std::vector` is invalidated when extension of buffer happens on `push_back()`. (I think more information should be in answer)

Answer (score 6):

Yes this is undifined behavior. When [std::vector::push_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) is called inside the loop, the iterator `i` might be invalidated (if the reallocation happends), then operation on it like `*i` is UB. And `l` is certain to be invalidated.

> If the new `size()` is greater than `capacity()` then all iterators and references (including the past-the-end iterator) are invalidated. Otherwise only the past-the-end iterator is invalidated.

You could use [std::vector::reserve](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) to avoid the reallocation and thus the invalidation of `i`. e.g.

```
vector<unsigned> vec;
vec.push_back(1); vec.push_back(3); vec.push_back(4); vec.push_back(5);

vec.reserve(vec.size() * 2);
for(vector<unsigned>::iterator i = vec.begin(); i != vec.end(); ++i) {
    cout<<(*i)<<"\n";
    vec.push_back(2);
    ++i;
    cout<<(*i)<<"\n";
}
```

Note you should use `vec.end()` directly to avoid the invalidation of `l` (the past-the-end iterator), and `++i` twice at the end of the iteration to avoid an infinite loop.

Comment: Ok...thanks...but what do you mean by:  Otherwise only the past-the-end iterator is invalidated

Comment: @JannatArora Since the size changes the `end()` method must return a new value, so the old one is invalid

Comment: @JannatArora It means if reallocation doesn't happen, only `l` will become invalid, `i` will be fine.

Comment: this code doesn't seem to do what the original code did, e.g it will skip half the output